# JQuery: Grab DIV class onClick and mirror to textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsbin.com/OYodAvo/1/edit

Today I was wondering if there's a way to grab a div's class that's already been clicked and mirror the class name to a textbox and set it as the value.
If another div has been clicked, replace it with that one.

Is there anyway to do this in JQuery?

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grab Element's DIV</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <center>
      <p>
        Grab DIV Class Onclick: <input type="text" id="divclass" placeholder="show class name here" />
      </p>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="im-red"></div>
        <div class="blue-foo"></div>
        <div class="green-beans"></div>
      </div>
    </center>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(function() {
  $(".wrapper div").click(function() {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
$(function() {
  $(".wrapper div").click(function() {
    $("#divclass").val($(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vn8q5/)

Comment: I swear I did this, after reviewing my history I put one t in attr lmao

Comment: don't worry, sometimes we don't see the smalls mistakes :)

Comment: I feel you there. Ahhh that was funny.

Comment: @mikethedj4 hehehehehe :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.wrapper div').click(function(){
    $('#divclass').val(this.className);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FJzGK/).

References:

- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).